# Python sharing a dictionnary composed of lists in multiprocess

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

Sorry if the question was already asked.

I would like to increase the speed of my code using multiprocessing.
I am generating data merged in lists in a dictionary. I cannot generate my dictionary properly and I don't known how to make it work. I saw that we can shared dictionaries in multiprocessing but I could find how to merge values that are set as lists of values.

This is what I did:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools
import random
import numpy as np

aa = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

data_list = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    n = random.randint(1,100)
    data_list.append(n)
n = 4
split_d = np.array_split(data_list, n)
d_len = {0: 0}
x = len(split_d[0])
for i in range(1, n, 1):
    d_len[i] = x
    x += len(d_len)


def run(sel):
    global data_list
    data_c = data_list.copy()
    tmp_res = {}
    for a, b in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(aa, 2):
        tmp_res[frozenset((a, b))] = []
    for k1 in split_d[sel]:
        a1, d1 = k1[0], int(k1[1], 2)
        for k2 in data_c:
            a2, d2 = k2[0], int(k2[1], 2)
            tmp_res[frozenset((a1, a2))].append(d1*d2)
        del data_c[d_len[sel]]

    for k in tmp_res:
        return k, tmp_res[k]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(n)
    results = dict(pool.map(run, range(0, n, 1)))
```

At the end, my dictionary `results` only contains one key with the list of values, instead of all the keys and lists generated during the process.

Any idea?

Comment: This is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); you are missing declarations for `data_list` and `data_len`. Also, the *sel* argument to `run` is not being referenced so each of the 4 tasks will be returning the same 4 return values, right (Id didn't see any randomness in the function)? What is the usefulness of that?

Comment: I just wanted to give a quick overview of the method I used. I made modifications. Better?

Answer (score 1):

I can get you started, but I believe you have some serious errors. Your first problem is in `run` you have:

```py
    for k in tmp_res:
        return k, tmp_res[k]
```

How many times do you think you will be executing that `return` statement in the loop? This is clearly wrong. You want to be returning the complete dictionary and in the main program have:

```py
    results = {}
    pool = mp.Pool(n, initializer=init_processes, initargs=(aa, data_list, split_d))
    for d in pool.map(run, range(0, n, 1)):
        results.update(d)
    print(results)
```

Note that in the above creation of the pool I am using the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments. You did not state what platform you are running under but if it is one that uses *spawn* to create new processes, such as Windows, then all code at global scope will be executed by all subprocesses. It is therefore not only inefficient, but in this case where you would like to see each subprocess start off with the same exact random data, also incorrect for each subprocess to be re-creating the `data_list` variable. Therefore this code should be moved inside a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block and the main process should initialize global variables for each pool process as necessary.

It also seems when I run this that you have errors in `run` with the statements:

```py
        a1, d1 = k1[0], int(k1[1], 2)
```

and

```py
            a2, d2 = k2[0], int(k2[1], 2)
```

The problem is that `k1` and `k2` are scalars that can't be indexed. So I don't know how you are able to return anything.

The complete modified code:

```py
import itertools

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing as mp
    import random
    import numpy as np

    aa = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

    data_list = []
    for i in range(0,1000):
        n = random.randint(1,100)
        data_list.append(n)
    n = 4
    split_d = np.array_split(data_list, n)
    d_len = {0: 0}
    x = len(split_d[0])
    for i in range(1, n, 1):
        d_len[i] = x
        x += len(d_len)


def init_processes(aa_arg, data_list_arg, split_d_arg):
    global aa, data_list, split_d

    aa, data_list, split_d = aa_arg, data_list_arg, split_d_arg


def run(sel):
    data_c = data_list.copy()
    tmp_res = {}
    for a, b in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(aa, 2):
        tmp_res[frozenset((a, b))] = []
    for k1 in split_d[sel]:
        a1, d1 = k1[0], int(k1[1], 2)
        for k2 in data_c:
            a2, d2 = k2[0], int(k2[1], 2)
            tmp_res[frozenset((a1, a2))].append(d1*d2)
        del data_c[d_len[sel]]

    return tmp_res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = {}
    pool = mp.Pool(n, initializer=init_processes, initargs=(aa, data_list, split_d))
    for d in pool.map(run, range(0, n, 1)):
        results.update(d)
    print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You were very fast! 
Good idea to treat the dictionaries with ```update```. 
Quick question: Why do you import itertools in the function?

Comment: No great reason; it doesn't save on efficiency because even the main process will be compiling `run` so it will import it. But it documents that only `run` needs to use it. Feel free to move it outside. But you can see why I have moved the other imports, right? The subprocesses do not need to import those modules on Windows and it will save processing time.

Comment: I moved the import statement. It is probably better globally or within the `init_processes` function.